# Gnome-builder Run button doesn't run. It installs

Tags: c++, ninja, meson-build, gnome-builder

I have set up a simple hello world in C++ with `meson` & `ninja` as a build chain. The project compiles just fine, but when I press the `Run` button it just runs ninja and then ninja install:

```
ninja
ninja install
ninja: no work to do.
[0/1] Installing files.
Nothing to install.
```

I get the following warning as well:

```
ide-run-manager[ 17574]:  WARNING: Failed to locate any build targets
```

```
# meson.build
project('test', 'cpp')
executable('hello', 'src/main.cpp')
```

I have been digging around in the very limited settings of gnome-builder and haven't been able to find any place to set what build target `Run` should run. I just want it to run my `hello` program.

Edit:
I found the solution at [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/crv934/gnome_builder_command_line_tool_template_disabled/). You have to mark the executable as install. Then gnome-builder installs the application and runs it.

Comment: you'd better post edit (copy-inserting solution as text or screenshot) as answer to question, this'll make things clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found at [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/crv934/gnome_builder_command_line_tool_template_disabled/exa52la/)

[image]